# Making certain number of table view cells fit on any device size in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

How would I make it so that the table view cells have a certain aspect ratio.

How do I achieve this.

If possible, please given an example of w:h 16:4, and is it possible to set this aspect ratio in the interface builder on the storyboard.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving the tableView a height proportional to screen and in heightForCellAtRow

```
 return heightOFTable/numberOfCells
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a delegate function you can call to adjust the height of the cells based on the indexpath. something like:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt 
    indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.tableview.frame.width / 4
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Storyboard like this. Embed a `UIView` in your template cell, you can make it transparent and put it in the back. Stretch it to the edges and set constraints to all four edges. Now, make the a width constraint with same width as its superview. Then add an aspect constraint `16:4` with a `priority` of `999`. The priority is needed to resolve a layout conflict you will otherwise get because of how sizing is working.

[image]

[image]